# Varnish has to many nuked objects

Tags: varnish

I am a bit insecure when i look at the varnish stats (varnish-3.0.7 revision f544cd8):

```
SMA.s0.c_req             6539970        17.36 Allocator requests
SMA.s0.c_fail            1440999         3.82 Allocator failures
SMA.s0.c_bytes      349031947792    926406.40 Bytes allocated
SMA.s0.c_freed      331852353844    880808.03 Bytes freed
SMA.s0.g_alloc            640358          .   Allocations outstanding
SMA.s0.g_bytes       17179593948          .   Bytes outstanding
SMA.s0.g_space            275236          .   Bytes available
SMA.Transient.c_req      3114278         8.27 Allocator requests
SMA.Transient.c_fail           0         0.00 Allocator failures
SMA.Transient.c_bytes 219115114784    581578.98 Bytes allocated
SMA.Transient.c_freed 219114814592    581578.18 Bytes freed
SMA.Transient.g_alloc          108          .   Allocations outstanding
SMA.Transient.g_bytes       300192          .   Bytes outstanding
SMA.Transient.g_space            0          .   Bytes available
```

Varnish is running with 16GB ram but i have lots of nuked objects.

```
n_lru_nuked            1428292          .   N LRU nuked objects
```

Is there something wrong with the memory settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `SMA.s0.g_space` value is `275236`, which is less than a megabyte. Your `SMA.s0.g_bytes` takes up nearly 16GB. This matches the amount of memory you mentioned.

The `MAIN.n_object` counter will give you an indication of the number of objects in the cache.

The question you should ask yourself is: *are all these objects supposed to be in the cache?* If that is the case, you should consider upgrading your sever and allocate more memory to Varnish.

If that's not the case, have a look at `MAIN.n_expired` to see how many objects have already expired and maybe lower the TTLs of your objects.

You can also monitor backend requests and check the size of the response that is about to get stored in the cache. Run the following command to do this:

```
varnishlog -g request -b -i berequrl -i Length -q "TTL[10] eq 'cacheable'"
```

You can also check the size of cached responses being served, this can also give you a clear indication:

```
varnishlog -g request -c -i requrl -I RespHeader:Content-Length -q "VCL_call eq 'HIT'"
```

Based on all that information you know how many objects are in the cache, and what the object sizes are that are being cached and served. You'll also have the URLs of the requests for these objects.

That will allow you to decide to either upgrade the memory on your Varnish server or lower the TTL of certain objects.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations. But arent objects stored in allocated memory via SMA.s0.g_bytes. What is the difference between g_space and g_bytes? I assume the g_space is space one object allocates. How to raise the g_space if it helps to get less nuked objects? Thank you again :)

Comment: The command above does not work for varnish3 as there is no -g parameter.

Comment: @MichaelLeiss https://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.0/reference/varnish-counters.html#sma-malloc-stevedore-counters describes the SMA counters. `g_bytes` is *Number of bytes allocated from the storage.*. Whereas `g_space` is *Number of bytes left in the storage.* according to the docs.

Comment: @MichaelLeiss Increasing the size of the cache can be done via tuning the `-s` runtime parameter as described in https://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.0/reference/varnishd.html#storage-backend

Comment: @MichaelLeiss Please DO NOT USE Varnish version 3. It has been EOL for ages. Varnish 3 is dead, so are Varnish 4 and 5. The only supported versions are Varnish 6.0 LTS, Varnish 7.1 & Varnish 7.2.

Hardly any of the commands I've given you will work in Varnish 3 and there are probably no corresponding commands for Varnish 3.